# VBA removes slashes

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA in excel. So, i create a string from multiple parts and output it in a cell on some sheet like this:

```
Sheets("Output").Cells(iRow, 1).Value = LArray(0) + "?" + adding + "/#" + LArrayNew(1)
```

I am expecting: `text?text/#text` 
But result on excel sheet is: `text?text#text`

Where is the "/"?

Comment: Use & to concatenate strings in VBA. I can run the following for example: Debug.Print "text?text" & "/#" & "text"

Comment: The `+` sign makes VBA to try to calculate with `"/#"` like it was a number and this results in a strange behavior here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim LArray(0 To 1) As String
    Dim adding As String, LArrayNew(0 To 1) As String

    adding = "X"
    LArrayNew(1) = "New"
    LArray(0) = "0"
    iRow = 1

    Sheets("Output").Cells(iRow, 1).Value = LArray(0) & "?" & adding & "/#" & LArrayNew(1)
End Sub
```

will produce:

**0?X/#New**

Note the slash is there!

[image]

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  I did miss the change...................I fixed it now ............. **Thanks for the help**